# What is the front page path of the Recruiter Distribution?

Tags: panels

I am using the [Recruiter distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter) and I want to find the path of the front page so as to add it to the 404 redirect settings of the site.
However,there is no panel page as homepage.There is only used the context module that says if path=< front > then etc.Also I tried the path /node with no luck.

So how can I find the path of the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recruiter Distribution, does not have a path where you can modify everything.

Everything is base on blocks and they are using the the Context module to display it.

1. **Menu** that it can be modify at `admin/structure/menu/manage/user-menu/`
2. **Block** The name of the region is called Banner. On the recruiter installation this block is blank.
3. **Views block.** If you wish to modify search you can go to `admin/structure/views/view/job_search/edit/search_page` to modify the location you can go to the context module.
4. **Block** That is blank on the Recruiter installation but is also a block and it can be modify at the context.
5. **Views Block** the views can be modify at `admin/structure/views/view/front_page_job_search` and the location at the context module.
6. **Block** That is blank on the Recruiter installation but is also a block and it can be modify at the context.
7. **Facets** To modify the location you need to the context page and to modify the look you would need to used the Facet Api module.

The rest of the footer it suppose to be at context module and they are many blocks.

[image]

**If you wish to have it on a path.** You probably would need to uninstall the `recruiter_front` module and then you need to make sure that any of the blocks that are pointing the the front page are gone. At this post you should have an empty page.  After that is going a default Drupal configuration. You can go to `/admin/config/system/site-information` and set a path that you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Is there a way to add the path of the frontpage to redirect the 404 page?

Comment: I have updated my answer with this question.

Comment: Thanks darol for the answer,unfortunalately I don't want to unistall recruiter_front module.I will try to find a module to redirect 404 pages or use a rule for this.Thanks again

Comment: To redirect pages you can used the Redirect module.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it at `/admin/config/system/site-information`. This is the value the `<front>` path uses.

**UPDATE**:
The default frontpage after a fresh install appears to be `/node` as defined per `/admin/config/system/site-information`

Comment: Hi,the Default front page is empty :(

Comment: Then you might want to update your question with details about what repository you are using. There is probably a custom module there handling the frontpage somehow. Or, the frontpage is just defined as the url without suffix.

Comment: I don't use any repository,I have set up a local version of the recruiter distribution,not sure if this is of any help...

Comment: Apologies, I meant distribution. I wanted to take a look for you, but installation is slow.

Comment: Just checked a fresh install, but frontpage should be /node

Comment: Thank you help so far.Actually I added "node" to the path of the 404 page but when I visit a 404 page,I am redirected to the /node page,which is not the homepage.Under /node page,I can see a list of nodes. :(

Comment: What appears at `/admin/config/system/site-information`?

Answer (score 1):

what is your problem with this code

```
<?php
    global $base_url;
    print $base_url;
 ?>
```

No matters what configuration is in system setting, it returns the address of front page.

Comment: Aha,thanks for the info.Is there any other way to redirect to homepage with the help of a module?

Comment: Install `redirect` module from https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect and in its configuration you may redirect to home page.

Comment: Hi Drupalist,I just installed Redirect module,however there is no configuration to redirect 404 pages automatically to frontpage,this needs to be done manually by selecting one by one 404 page.

Comment: Why don't you do this using .htaccess? from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363520/redirecting-404-error-with-htaccess I found it, use this code `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`